# What type of data modelling should I use?

Tags: web, data-modeling

I am currently developing a website, and basically I want to store and display user submissions. The submission would be text only (a lot like FML, or MLIA), so I was wondering what would be the best way to store/manipulate this data?

Comment: A relational database like MySQL, SQLite, or PostgreSQL would do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for any website the best way to model data is to use a database.

This depends very much on your website's needs, size, and other criterias, so one cannot state what database system you should use or if you should use a relational one or a NO-SQL one.